# Swiftui specify double format

Tags: swift, xcode, format, swiftui, specifier

```
Text("Värde \(Double(calc2, specifier: "%.2f").rounded())")
```

//ERROR

I am converting a `Slider` value that uses a double type, but i cant format specify it?
I get an error and xcode tells me to use signaling(?). I've tried putting it into an `Int` as well.

whats the right move here?

Answer (score 18):

You can use

```swift
Text("Värde \(calc2, specifier: "%.2f")")
```

to convert it to 2 decimals.

To have greater flexibility you can use formatter and leverage [appendInterpolation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/localizedstringkey/stringinterpolation/3270351-appendinterpolation) on string.  Use the below function or something to that effect

```swift
func customFormat(_ number: Double) -> String  {
   let customFormatter = NumberFormatter()
   customFormatter.roundingMode = .down
   customFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

   return "\(number, formatter: customFormatter)"   
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I assume you want something like

```
Text("Värde \(String(format: "%.2f", calc2))")
```

Comment: Thats the old, compatible style. Looks like `specifier:` was added in SwiftUI

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Double(calc2, specifier: "%.2f")` is optional

to handle it, for example, use `Double(calc2, specifier: "%.2f")?.rounded() ?? 0.0`